# Is there a way to get single file output without the DLL and config files from Neutralino?

Tags: javascript, neutralinojs

I tried Neutralino.js, everything is great except I can't build the project into one executable, but there is a DLL and a config file. I don't want them to be visible and I want to be able to distribute it in a single file. What I'm currently doing is using `iexpress` to make self-extracting executables. It works, but it's not ideal. Is there a way to get a single file from `neu build`?

Comment: the `resources.neu` contains your config and all the resources file, and hence currently there is not tool which can merge it, and for DLLs we look into it.